# Traffic light sequence

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have create a functioning automated traffic light sequence using an array and `if` statements. It all work correctly but I am wondering if there is anything more I can do to improve my code without changing to structure or way it works, so without the use of dictionaries, etc.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
 <title> Traffic Light</title> 
 
 <style>
  .rainbow {
   background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, red), color-stop(0.1, yellow), color-stop(0.2, green));
   background-image: gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );
   color:transparent;
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   background-clip: text;
  }
 </style>

</head>

<body background="street.gif">
 <h1 class="rainbow">Traffic Light</h1>
  
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="300"
 style="border:1px solid #000000;">
 Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
 </canvas>
 
 
 <script>   
 
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  ctx.rect(0, 0, 200, 300);
  ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
  ctx.fill();

  var colours=["red", "yellow", "green", "black","red yellow"];
  var current=colours[0];

  function offlight() {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(95,50,40,10,12*Math.PI);
   ctx.fillStyle = "black";
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.stroke();
  }
 
  function offlight1() {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(95,150,40,10,12*Math.PI);
   ctx.fillStyle = "black";
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.stroke();
  }
 
  function offlight2() {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(95,250,40,10,12*Math.PI);
   ctx.fillStyle = "black";
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.stroke();
  }
 
  function drawLight1() {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(95,50,40,10,12*Math.PI);
   ctx.fillStyle = "red";
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.stroke();
  }
 
  function drawLight2() {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(95,150,40,10,12*Math.PI);
   ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.stroke();
  }

  function drawLight3() {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(95,250,40,10,12*Math.PI);
   ctx.fillStyle = "green";
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.stroke();
  }

  function changelight(){

   if (current==colours[0]){
    drawLight1();
    offlight1();
    offlight2();
    current=colours[4]
   } else if (current==colours[4]){
    drawLight1();
    drawLight2();
    offlight2();
    current=colours[2]
   } else if (current==colours[2]) {
    offlight();
    offlight1();
    drawLight3();
    current=colours[3]
   } else if (current==colours[3]){
    offlight();
    drawLight2();
    offlight2();
    current=colours[0]
   }

  }
  setInterval(changelight,1000);

 </script>
  
 <br><br>
 <button onclick="changelight()">Click</button>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, you moved your `<h1>` into the `<body>`. Still, what exactly are you looking for? File size (--> code reduction)? Speed optimization?

One simple thing would be using `parameters` to reduce code duplication:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.rect(0, 0, 200, 300);
ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
ctx.fill();

var colours = ["red", "yellow", "green",  "red yellow"];
var current = colours[0];

function offlight(a1) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(95, a1, 40, 10, 12 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawLight(a1, fillParam) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(95, a1, 40, 10, 12 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = fillParam;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function changelight() {
    if (current == colours[0]) {
        drawLight(50, "red");
        offlight(150);
        offlight(250);
        current = colours[4]
    } else if (current == colours[4]) {
        drawLight(50, "red");
        drawLight(150, "yellow");
        offlight(250);
        current = colours[2]
    } else if (current == colours[2]) {
        offlight(50);
        offlight(150);
        drawLight(250, "green");
        current = colours[1]
    } else if (current == colours[1]) {
        offlight(50);
        drawLight(150, "yellow");
        offlight(250);
        current = colours[0]
    }

}
setInterval(changelight, 1000);
```

Do you ever use [colours](https://jsfiddle.net/cLL3xLex/)? ("yellow")

You could also remove the whitespaces and shorten variable and function names. Also think about moving your JS into a separate file.

[Here is a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/cLL3xLex/)

Comment: I have nothing in particular i am looking for it is just i am new to JavaScript and I was wondering if there were any silly mistakes i had made, colours[1] should be being used colours[2] i need to get rid of. And with regards to the code snippet I for some reason cannot get that to work?

Comment: The snippet should work. [Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/k9ny4cje/) There were no mistakes. However you might find it useful to know the difference between `==` and `===`. [Here is a short summary.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript) Usually it's considered "safer" to use `===`.

Answer (score 2):

The `colours` array isn't doing anything for you.  If anything, it just obfuscates the code.  This…

> ```
> if (current == colours[0]) {
>     drawLight(50, "red");
>     offlight(150);
>     offlight(250);
>     current = colours[4]
> ```

… would be clearer if written as

```
if (current == "red") {
    drawLight(50, "red");
    offlight(150);
    offlight(250);
    current = "red yellow";
```

It's confusing that the cycle goes 0 → 4 → 2 → 3 → 0 …, such that `colors[1]` is never used.  **The worst part of the obfuscation is that `colors[3]`, which is labelled `"black"`, actually represents the yellow light state.**

Instead of an if-else chain, you should define the behaviour of the lights in an array, and make a state machine.  (Here, I've used an associative array, which you seem not to like.  There are other ways to do it without the associative array, which would probably be uglier.)

```js
var lightStates = [
    {'top': 'red',   'mid': 'black',  'bottom': 'black'}, //   ←──────╮
    {'top': 'red',   'mid': 'yellow', 'bottom': 'black'}, //  │ cycle │
    {'top': 'black', 'mid': 'black',  'bottom': 'green'}, //  │       │
    {'top': 'black', 'mid': 'yellow', 'bottom': 'black'}, //  ╰───────╯
];

var lightPositions = {
    'top': 50, 'mid': 150, 'bottom': 250,
};

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.rect(0, 0, 200, 300);
ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
ctx.fill();

function drawLight(name, color) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(95, lightPositions[name], 40, 10, 12 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
};

var state = -1;
function changeLights() {
    state = (state + 1) % lightStates.length;
    for (var name in lightStates[state]) {
        drawLight(name, lightStates[state][name]);
    }
};

setInterval(changeLights, 1000);
```

```css
.rainbow {
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, red), color-stop(0.1, yellow), color-stop(0.2, green));
 background-image: gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );
 color:transparent;
 -webkit-background-clip: text;
 background-clip: text;
}

#myCanvas {
 border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Traffic Light</title> 
</head>
<body>
 <h1 class="rainbow">Traffic Light</h1>
  
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="300">
 Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
 </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Your HTML is malformed — there is no opening `<html>` tag.

Avoid attributes like `background="street.gif"` and `style="border:1px solid #000000;"`.  Those should be written using CSS instead.